# Weird Scatter Plot Issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm having this weird glitch with ggplot where my 913 and 995 values are being placed all the way to the right of the scatterplot. I have no clue why it's doing this. My code is down below and a link to the image it projects. Really appreciate anyone's help! I'm a newbie
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNuz9.png

```
library(tidyverse)
subject = c(1:19)
gender = c("M","M","F","F","F","F","M","F","F","M","F","F","F","F","M","M")
mass = c(62.0, 62.9, 36.1, 54.6, 48.5, 42.0, 47.4, 50.6, 42.0, 48.7, 40.3, 34.5, 51.1, 41.2, 51.9, 46.9)
rate = c(1792, 1666,995, 1425, 1396, 1418, 1362, 1502, 1256, 1614, 1189, 913, 1460, 1124, 1052, 1347, 1204, 1867, 1439)
bmr = as.data.frame(cbind(subject, gender, mass, rate))
print(bmr)

ggplot(data = bmr, aes(x = rate, y = mass)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

Image to projected plot:

Comment: `cbind` means that `bmr$rate` is now a vector of string factors; see the linked question for ways to avoid that.

Comment: ```gender``` and ```mass``` has 16 rows while ```subject``` and ```bmr``` has 19. Is this something intended?

Answer (score 0):

That is because, both mass and rate columns are character in the data frame bmr, subject and rate has length 19 and gender and mass has length 16 correct these lengths if these are not correct.

to get the desired plot, you can convert rate and mass to numeric first or, you can covert these variables to numeric within the ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
subject = c(1:19)
gender = c("M","M","F","F","F","F","M","F","F","M","F","F","F","F","M","M")
mass = c(62.0, 62.9, 36.1, 54.6, 48.5, 42.0, 47.4, 50.6, 42.0, 48.7, 40.3, 34.5, 51.1, 41.2, 51.9, 46.9)
rate = c(1792, 1666,995, 1425, 1396, 1418, 1362, 1502, 1256, 1614, 1189, 913, 1460, 1124, 1052, 1347, 1204, 1867, 1439)
bmr = as.data.frame(cbind(subject, gender, mass, rate))
print(bmr)
str(bmr)

ggplot(data = bmr, aes(x = as.numeric(rate), y = as.numeric(mass))) + 
geom_point(size=3) + 
geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA3sJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that there are 16 values for `gender` and `mass`, but 19 for `subject` and `rate`. So, this means that to make a dataframe out of these four strings (columns), then R needs a way to make them all the same length. In this instance, it has reused/recycled the first three elements of the shorter strings. R does warn you about this, and as you can see below the last three values of `gender` and `mass` are the same as the first three.

```
bmr = as.data.frame(cbind(subject, gender, mass, rate))
# Warning message:
#   In cbind(subject, gender, mass, rate) :
#   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

print(bmr)
#    subject gender mass rate
# 1        1      M   62 1792
# 2        2      M 62.9 1666
# 3        3      F 36.1  995
# 4        4      F 54.6 1425
# 5        5      F 48.5 1396
# 6        6      F   42 1418
# 7        7      M 47.4 1362
# 8        8      F 50.6 1502
# 9        9      F   42 1256
# 10      10      M 48.7 1614
# 11      11      F 40.3 1189
# 12      12      F 34.5  913
# 13      13      F 51.1 1460
# 14      14      F 41.2 1124
# 15      15      M 51.9 1052
# 16      16      M 46.9 1347
# 17      17      M   62 1204
# 18      18      M 62.9 1867
# 19      19      F 36.1 1439
```

Without knowing your data, I assume something needs attention; either you're missing `gender` and `mass` details for the last three subjects, or you've got three extra values for `rate` for some reason.

Anyway, let's proceed assuming the data is correct.

The first thing I would recommend is coverting `bmr` from a `data.frame` to a `tibble` (a `tibble` is a special type of `data.frame`). There isn't a heap of difference, but the main one here is that when you print a `tibble` to the console, it tells you what type of columns you have.

```
bmr_tib <- as_tibble(bmr)

bmr_tib
# # A tibble: 19 x 4
#    subject gender mass  rate 
#    <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>
# 1  1       M      62    1792 
# 2  2       M      62.9  1666 
# 3  3       F      36.1  995  
# 4  4       F      54.6  1425 
# 5  5       F      48.5  1396 
# 6  6       F      42    1418 
# 7  7       M      47.4  1362 
# 8  8       F      50.6  1502 
# 9  9       F      42    1256 
# 10 10      M      48.7  1614 
# 11 11      F      40.3  1189 
# 12 12      F      34.5  913  
# 13 13      F      51.1  1460 
# 14 14      F      41.2  1124 
# 15 15      M      51.9  1052 
# 16 16      M      46.9  1347 
# 17 17      M      62    1204 
# 18 18      M      62.9  1867 
# 19 19      F      36.1  1439
```

The info printed inside the `<  >` between the column names and the data indicates the data type. In this case, all of your columns are `<chr>`, which is short for `character`. This is not generally advised for numerical data, as by default I think R orders `chr` data alphabetically, rather than numerically. This is why the `995` and `913` are last in the plot, because `9` comes after `1` alphabetically. This is the reason your data points are in the wrong place on your plot.

You would keep data in `<chr>` format if there was no particular order to your data, or the data was alphabetically ordered anyway. This would be useful if you had people's names for example. Your data is also an example where number-type data may be safely kept in character format; I assume with the `subject` column, although it contains numbers is not necessarily ordered. This would be the case if that's the arbitrary order the subjects were measured or entered into a database, and it wouldn't matter if this order was changed (unlike our `mass` and `rate` data).

So, first up we want to convert your number data columns to numeric format. We use `as.numeric()` here, and can do this using `mutate()`. Check out the [R for Data Science book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) for everything you need to know about getting started in R, and explanations of `mutate()` and other useful functions.

```
bmr_tib_num <- bmr_tib %>% 
  mutate(
    mass = as.numeric(mass),
    rate = as.numeric(rate),
  )

bmr_tib_num
# # A tibble: 19 x 4
#    subject gender  mass  rate
#    <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1       M       62    1792
# 2  2       M       62.9  1666
# 3  3       F       36.1   995
# 4  4       F       54.6  1425
# 5  5       F       48.5  1396
# 6  6       F       42    1418
# 7  7       M       47.4  1362
# 8  8       F       50.6  1502
# 9  9       F       42    1256
# 10 10      M       48.7  1614
# 11 11      F       40.3  1189
# 12 12      F       34.5   913
# 13 13      F       51.1  1460
# 14 14      F       41.2  1124
# 15 15      M       51.9  1052
# 16 16      M       46.9  1347
# 17 17      M       62    1204
# 18 18      M       62.9  1867
# 19 19      F       36.1  1439
```

Notice now the `mass` and `rate` columns are of type `<dbl>`, this means "double class" and refers to the way computers store numbers (see [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-does-dbl-in-r-stand-for/30599)). So basically - `<dbl>` means numeric.

So, now that our data is in a numeric format, R knows the values of `913` and `995` come first in the data. So, we can plot again:

```
ggplot(data = bmr_tib_num, aes(x = rate, y = mass)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

[image]

So, there's three main differences between this plot and yours: 1) the points are now in numerical order and so are arranged properly, 2) the axes have even spacings between labels, rather than a label for each data point (this is a telltale sign you have non-numeric format data), and 3) the `geom_smooth()` line has appeared - I assume this is because R now has numbers to work with it is able to run a linear model on the data.

Hope this helps. I would highly recommend reading and working through the examples in the [R for Data Science book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html) if you want to ease the learning curve of R, and reduce your stress when starting out.